# LyX 2.0.3 Mac Version unavailable article document class

Tags: packages, lyx

I am trying to use LyX 2.0.3 but for some reason it does not have the Document class article. Is there something else I need to install? I have installed TeXworks as well but for some reason it still can't find most of the document classes. An example of the error I get is

```
The module enumitem requires a package that is not available 
in your laTex installation, or a converter that you have not installed. 
LaTex output may not be possible. Missing Prerequisites:

enumitem.sty
```

So when I navigate to Document -> Settings, in the document class box most things are unavailable. Any advice would be great!

Comment: Did you install MacTeX or some other TeX distribution?

Comment: I did install MaxTeX but still made no difference. I solved it now by copying the layouts folder from the resource folder into the application support lye folder